# Put two and two together idiom

Tags: idioms

Can we use the "put two and two together" idiom in the general meaning of being good at solving problems?

Example:

> At work, I put two and two together connecting questions and answers with the right people.

Comment: It is usually used with single instances, not with processes in general. *I was initially confused by his behavior that day, but later I put two and two together.* It refers to making a deduction - figuring out the circumstances where things add up.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with that. Normally it means "to use common sense":

> Come on, you can put two and two together just like anyone. Figure it out.

But then of course you can consider building on that:

> She really knows how to put two and two together.

That would be a perfectly acceptable, even catchy, idiom to indicate someone is sharp-witted, good at solving problems and figuring things out, and so on.

Your usage sounds a little strained, but it is totally comprehensible. For some reason, this sounds a little more natural:

> I was *able to/managed to put two and two together,* connecting ... with the right people.

There's something about the phrase when referring to oneself that seems to make the speaker want to understate a bit, perhaps to deflect a charge of arrogance? Also, the "connecting questions and answers with the right people" bit itself seems odd. "...connecting with the right people who could answer my questions" might be better.